# Appending Apache log files with the date

Tags: logging, apache-log-files

I used to use *cronolog* to manage my Apache log files. However, after getting back into website hosting, I noticed it is no longer being updated.

I want to append the date of the log file, so I have a new file each day. (i.e., *apache-error_2014-05-02.log*) instead of the typical *error.log1*, *error.log2*, *error.log3* that Apache does.

How can I do this with Apache?

Comment: Reworded, to reopen. Apache supports this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/rotatelogs.html

Comment: @pritaeas Re-opened so you might add the link, with some elaboration, as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Apache supports rotating logfiles. Check the manual [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/rotatelogs.html), specifically the following example:

```
CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs -l /var/logs/logfile.%Y.%m.%d 86400" common
```